# How to implement jsonp get request in ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, jsonp

This is my code.

```
     this.jsonp.request(url, { method: 'Get' })
     .map(res => res.json()})
     .subscribe(
        data => {
         //success code
        },
        error => {
         //error code
        }
      )
```

Problem is that function always executes error code block. And in the browser response is 200 ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
Note: import Httpmodule and inject to appmodule

import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
......
......

 public http: Http,
.....
......

        let url="http://XXXX.XXXXX.XXXXX/1/forms";//put URL of JSON here

        this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(resp => {

          console.log(resp);
         });
```